# Cannot mount USB on FreeBSD: Invalid argument

Tags: mount, usb, freebsd, usb-drive, macintosh

I'm trying to mount a USB stick on FreeBSD. The result of `camcontrol devlist` is:

```
root@machine0:~ # camcontrol devlist
<APPLE SSD SM0128G BXW1JA0Q>       at scbus0 target 0 lun 0 (ada0,pass0)
< USB DISK 1100>                   at scbus1 target 0 lun 0 (da0,pass1)
<APPLE SD Card Reader 3.00>        at scbus2 target 0 lun 0 (da1,pass2)
```

I did

```
root@machine0:~ # mount /dev/da0 /mnt
mount: /dev/da0: Invalid argument
```

Specifying the file system doesn't help either:

```
root@machine0:~ # mount -t fat /dev/da0 /mnt
mount: /dev/da0: Operation not supported by device
```

Output of `gpart show da0`:

```
=>      34  15730621  da0  GPT  (7.5G)
        34         6       - free -  (3.0K)
        40    409600    1  efi  (200M)
    409640      2008       - free -  (1.0M)
    411648  15316992    2  ms-basic-data  (7.3G)
  15728640      2015       - free -  (1.0M)
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `gpart show da0`? Its also probably `mount -t msdosfs /dev/da0 /mnt`.

Comment: @MartinSugioarto Output added. I did `mount -t msdosfs /dev/da0p2 /mnt`, and it mounted successfully!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to mount a specific partition, not the whole drive. You can try something like `da0x`, where x is replaced by the desired partition id. You can look in `/dev` to find partition id's on `da0`.

Comment: It's usually the `i` partition for DOS, i.e. `/dev/da0i`.

Comment: "You can look in `/dev` to find partition id's on `da0`." How to do this? `ls` says `/dev/da0` isn't a directory...

Comment: You can do: ls /dev/da0*

Comment: @diametralpitch I saw `/dev/da0 /dev/da0p1 /dev/da0p2`. However, trying to mount either `/dev/da0p1` or `/dev/da0p2` gives me the `Invalid argument` error……

Comment: @diametralpitch Finally I find out that `mount -t msdosfs /dev/da0p2 /mnt` is the magic spell. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a nasty trick:

```
/etc/autofs/special_media
```

Just run this, as root.  It doesn't really use autofs, and doesn't need it to be configured, it's just a script autofs normally uses.  It will show you all the devices that are available for mounting, but skip ones that are "claimed", because there are eg paritions on them, or because they are already mounted.  For example, if you have da0 and da0s1, it will only show the latter.

You can also use fstyp(8) to determine the filesystem type, like this (as root):

```
fstyp /dev/da0s1
```